Can I directly assign a new object reference variable to the original current object, inside the object class?
Lets say I am trying to reverse a SinglyLinkedList object list. I would do so like this:
public void reverseList() {
    SinglyLinkedList<E> reverse = new SinglyLinkedList<>();
    Node<E> present = head;
    while(present != null) {
        reverse.addFirst(present.getElement());
        present = present.getNext();
    }
    this.head = reverse.head;
    this.tail = reverse.tail;
    this.size = reverse.size;       
}

Ok, this is fine. But, is there a way I can just point the new reversed lists reference varibale to the old current one inside this 'reverseList()' method? Such as:
public void reverseList() {
SinglyLinkedList<E> reverse = new SinglyLinkedList<>();
Node<E> present = head;
while(present != null) {
    reverse.addFirst(present.getElement());
    present = present.getNext();
}
this = reverse; // I know this is syntacally wrong... but you get my point  
}

And yes, I know I can just return the new reversed list and point the old current one to it in the main method like this:
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SinglyLinkedList<Integer> list = new SinglyLinkedList<>();
    list.addFirst(10);
    list.addLast(20);
    list.addLast(30);
    list.printList(); // Output: 10 20 30
    list = list.reverseList();
    list.printList(); // Output: 30 20 10
}

But my original point is if I can just change the current object pointer to the new one INSIDE the object class itself? Is this possible in Java? If not, can the devs do it?
as stated above. I explained

I don't think that's possible. As I know, from inside a class code the only connection to the object is this keyword. Since you can't assign variable to this, I don't see how this can be done.

No, it is not possible.

Consider a concurrent program. Thread 1 calls a method in a Person object. In the meantime thread 2 calls a method that replaces this to refer to a Student object (a subclass of Person) with a different implementation of the method that thread 1 is executing. What would you expect to happen then?

Though this works as a reference variable that refers to the current object, it's actually a java keyword, not an actual variable, that's why you can't assign any value to this.
Now, what you are trying to do is reverse a singly linked list and point the current object to it. So the best way you can opt for is in-place algorithm, that way you don't need to point to some new object, as your current object it self will be modified.
Example Code :
public void reverseList(ListNode head) {
    ListNode dummy = new ListNode(-1);
    ListNode currentNode = head;
        
    while(currentNode != null){
        ListNode nextNode = currentNode.next;
        currentNode.next = dummy.next;
        dummy.next = currentNode;
        currentNode = nextNode;
    }
    head = dummy.next;
}

